# HTML CSS footer design issue

Tags: html, css, footer

I am trying to build a website, and in my footer section I am facing an issue that, I can't properly position my

tag below the social media icons, and also cannot position the li elements "terms of use","content guidelines","report error" in a horizontal style.also i cannot remove the underline on the li after removing the text decor,and cannot remove the bullets from the li elements..pls help

[image: current model]

[image: required model]

```css
footer
{
width: 100%;
background-color: #2d2d2d;
padding: 80px 0px;
}
footer h2 {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #a1a1a1;
    text-transform: uppercase;
 margin-top: -20px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
 margin-left: 20px;
 

 
}
h2 {
    font-size: 20px;
 font-family: 'Gothic-Bold';
    font-weight: normal;
 position:sticky;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}


* {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

.ft-quick-links
{
 float:left;
 width:400px;
}
.ft-quick-links ul li{
 float:left;
 margin-right:6px;
 margin-bottom:20px;
 margin-left: 5px;
 list-style: none;
 padding-right: 5px;
 
 
}
.ft-quick-links li a{
 padding: 8px 15px;
 font-size: 13px;
 color: #959595;
 background:#202020 ;
 text-decoration: none;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.ft-quick-links li a:hover{
 background:#171717;
}
.footer-btm-wrapp{
 width:100%;
 display:table;
 background:#1b1b1b;
}
.ft-btm-left {
 float:left;
}
.ft-btm-left ul li{
 float:left;
 margin-right:40px;
}
.ft-btm-left ul li a{
 font-size:12px;
 color:#5f5f5f;
}
.ft-btm-left ul li a:hover{
 text-decoration:none;
}
.footer-btm-wrapp .wrapper{
 padding:20px 0px;
}
.ft-social ul li{
 float: right;
 padding-right: 20px;
 padding-top: 15px;
 list-style: none;
}
.footer-btm-wrapp .wrapper{
 padding:8px 0px;
 list-style: none;
}


.copy-rights p{
 color:#959595;
 font-size:13px;
 list-style: none;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 padding: 60px 20px 10px;
 float:right;
 text-align:right;
 list-style: none;
 
 
}
.wrapper{
 width:1100px;
 margin:0px auto;
 position:relative;
}

.ft-lines{
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #5f5f5f;
 list-style: none;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 text-decoration: none;
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
 <link rel="stylesheet"type="text/css" href="foot1.css">
<footer>
 
 <div class="wrapper">
 <div class="ft-quick-links">
  <h2>Quick Links</h2>
  <ul class="clearfix">
   <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Media</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Feedback</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Privacy policy</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="ft-social">
      <ul class="clearfix">  
       
   
   <li><a href="http://www.youtube.com"><img src="images/yt.png"/></a></li>
   <li><a href="http://www.instagram.com"><img src="images/ig.png"/></a></li>
   <li><a href="http://www.twitter.com"><img src="images/twit.png" /></a></li>
   <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com"><img src="images/fb.png" /></a></li>
 
   </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
   <div class="wrapper">
   <div class="ft-lines">
   <ul class="clearfix">
    <li><a href="#">Terms of Use</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Content Guidelines</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Report error </a></li>
 </ul> 
    <div class="copy-rights"><p> ©  2017 Rodeo labs. All rights reserved</p>
   </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </footer>
 
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What would you like the outcome to be?

Comment: A lot of the problems you're having can be found with 3 word google searches. At least try to find the solution to removing bullet points, removing underline, etc.. (btw remove bullets: "list-style-type: none;",  remove underline: "text-decoration:  none;")

Comment: Since you're not using any frameworks like bootstrap/materialize, you are writing CSS manually I suggest you draw the skeleton properly.
Then, styling will be much easier to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.ft-lines{
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-top: 25px; /*positioning li elements "terms of use","content guidelines","report error"*/
    
}

.ft-lines li {
    list-style: none; /*remove bullets*/ 
    display: inline; /*display in horizontal line li elements*/
    margin: 0 10px 0 10px; /*add spaces between links*/
}

.ft-lines a {
    text-decoration: none; /*removes underline on links*/
    color: #959595;
}

.ft-lines a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline; /*adds underline on links*/
}
```

jus remove your .ft-lines and add mine
hope this helped.

Comment: not worked properly.I made some changes, your code helped  a lot

Comment: But now I am facing a new problem, my li elements and social media icons are not working pls help..

Answer (score 1):

I hope this code will be useful to you

```css
footer
{width: 100%;background-color: #2d2d2d;/* padding: 54px 0px; */display: flex;height: 6vmin;}
footer h2 {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #a1a1a1;
    text-transform: uppercase;
 

 
}
h2 {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Gothic-Bold';
    font-weight: normal;
    /* position:sticky; */
}

.ft-quick-links
{
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
}

.ft-quick-links a{
 padding: 5px;
 font-size: 13px;
 color: #959595;
 background:#202020;
 text-decoration: none;
 /* margin-bottom: 30px; */
}
.ft-quick-links a:hover{
 background:#171717;
}
.footer-btm-wrapp{
 width:100%;
 display:table;
 background:#1b1b1b;
}
.ft-btm-left {
 float:left;
}

.ft-btm-left a{
 font-size:12px;
 color:#5f5f5f;
}
.ft-btm-left a:hover{
 text-decoration:none;
}

.ft-social i{
 float: right;
 padding-right: 20px;
 padding-top: 15px;
 list-style: none;
}


.copy-rights p{
 color:#959595;
 font-size:13px;
 list-style: none;
 text-align:right;
 list-style: none;
 
 
}

.ft-lines{
    /* font-size: 12px; */
    color: #5f5f5f;
    /* list-style: none; */
    /* margin-bottom: 10px; */
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<footer>
 
 <div class="ft-quick-links">
  <h2>Quick Links</h2>
  
   <a href="#">About</a>
   <a href="#">Media</a>
   <a href="#">Feedback</a>
   <a href="#">Privacy policy</a>
   
  </div>
  
  <div class="ft-quick-links">
       
       
   
   <a href="http://www.youtube.com"><img src="images/yt.png"></a>
   <a href="http://www.instagram.com"><img src="images/ig.png"></a>
   <a href="http://www.twitter.com"><img src="images/twit.png"></a>
   <a href="http://www.facebook.com"><img src="images/fb.png"></a>
 
  
  </div>
  
   <div class="ft-quick-links">
   
    <a href="#">Terms of Use</a>
    <a href="#">Content Guidelines</a>
    <a href="#">Report error </a><!--
--> 
    
   
 </div>
 <p> ©  2017 Rodeo labs. All rights reserved</p>
 </footer>
```

Comment: You must the complete answer

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the top 2 div.wrapper inside a div and style it. According to what you have done in styling, the third div.wrapper is inserted inside the top to in the DOM.

As well add bottom div.wrapper (which contains the divs for the three links and the copyrights) in a different context and do the stylings respectively.

If you're doing this for practice that's fine.
This code that you have written needs more improvement. In production code, this is not the recommended way of writing the code. Please follow some guidelines. Googling 'HTML and CSS best practices guidelines' will help you.

PS - Didn't edit your code since it needs a re-engineering.

Answer (score 0):

Try following in your css. I have added some comments.

```
.ft-lines ul li{
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block; # This will display li side by side
  padding-right: 10px; # add for have a bit of space
  }
.ft-lines ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  }

.ft-lines {
  clear: both; # to clear the floating elements
  float: right;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You are not using any framework like bootstrap or foundation. So, first of all, make a proper design of footer layout.
For example - 
<ul class="demo">
<li><a href="#">demo1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">demo2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">demo3</a></li>
</ul>

To remove bullet  from li use -
ul.demo li
{
list-style-type:none;
}
To remove text-decoration from a use -
.demo li a
{
text-decoration:none;
}
```